# Detect if user is logged in

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, navbar

This is some coding in my nav bar. I am trying to detect whether there is a user logged in or not. What's supposed to happen is when there is a user logged in then it shows a little dropdown menu with options for the user to edit their account or logout, but it's not working.

```
            <?php
            function loggedIn(){
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            if(isset($_SESSION['username'])!="")
            { echo '<li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'. $_SESSION['username'] .'<span class="caret"></span></a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>';
            }else{
                echo '<li><a href="#login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login" id="loginbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>';
                }
            }
            loggedIn();
            ?>
```

Comment: you set `$_SESSION['username']` and check on next line if isset ? what's the idea... ?

Comment: That must be generating compile errors, as `$username` has not been defined in the function and is not passed into the function as a parameter so it is therefore **out of scope**

Comment: Also you dont look like you have grabbed the session `session_start()` in this code, although that may be because you gave us a shortned version of your code

Answer (score 0):

The minute you set the $_SESSION['username'] variable, your test at if(isset($_SESSION['username'])!="") will always execute because the variable is set.
For my login process, I usually have a doLogin.php script that authenticates the user against the database and if the authentication passes, it sets the necessary $_SESSION variables. If it fails, its sets a $_SESSION['loginAttemptCount'] variable, and unsets the $_SESSION['username'] and associated variables.

This way, each PHP page simply executes the if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) test and configures itself accordingly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I should add that after authentication, the doLogin.php script forwards to either an authErr.php page or to a loginSuccess.php page.

Answer (score 0):

The normal process is :

- Login script creates something in the session
- Scripts that want to know if a user has logged in, check for that value in the session.

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// do all your login checks for userid / password

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

. . . .
```

any_other.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    function AddForLoggedInUsers(){

        if( !empty($_SESSION['username']) ) { 
           $htm = '<li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'. $_SESSION['username'] .'<span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>';
        }else{
            $htm = '<li><a href="#login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login" id="loginbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>';
        }

        return $htm;
    }

    // other code

    echo AddForLoggedInUsers();
```

Its also a better idea to place the html you generate in a function into a variable then when you call the function you have the option of adding to the functions result or just echoing it straight out, or possibly even modifying it.